# difference between hibernating and stopping an EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Obviously, [hibernation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/instance-hibernate-overview.html) and stop are two different actions that I can select.
What's the difference?

Comment: It's the same as Shutdown vs Hibernate on your own PC.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Benefit of Hibernating over Stopping**

- The memory state is preserved
- Since the memory state is perserved and loaded again when the instance start, this reduce the boot time of the instance.
- The long running process can continue without interuption
- A great benefit if you want to maintain the in-memory caching layer, or have some services that take a great amount of time to fully initialized.

**Under the hood**
The whole hibernation process in visual:
[image: Hibernation Process]

When the instance is in **Stopping** state, the instance memory is persisted in the instance's EBS root volume, and is loaded again when the instance start.

**Reference**
[AWS Instance Hibernate Overview](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-hibernate-overview.html)

Answer (score 3):

From the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Hibernate.html)

> When you hibernate an instance, Amazon EC2 signals the operating
> system to perform hibernation (suspend-to-disk). Hibernation saves the
> contents from the instance memory (RAM) to your Amazon Elastic Block
> Store (Amazon EBS) root volume. Amazon EC2 persists the instance's EBS
> root volume and any attached EBS data volumes. When you start your
> instance:
>
> - The EBS root volume is restored to its previous state
> - The RAM contents are reloaded
> - The processes that were previously running on the instance are resumed
> - Previously attached data volumes are reattached and the instance retains its instance ID

[Read more](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Hibernate.html)

Answer (score 3):

### TL;DR

When you `stop` your instance, the data stored in memory (RAM) is lost.

When you `stop-hibernate` an instance, AWS signals the OS to perform hibernation (suspend-to-disk), which saves the contents from the instance memory (RAM) to the Amazon EBS root volume.

From the charging perspective, AWS does not charge usage or data transfer fees for your instance after you stop it, but storage for any Amazon EBS volumes is still charged.

### A practical example

Suppose you want to build a caching layer (e.g. on top of your DB) in an EC2 instance. For such a case, the `stop-hibernate` feature would be instrumental in persisting storage. It would prevent you from having to manually create scripts to save the RAM data before shutting down the server.